# Data Split based on a logical relationship in R

Tags: python, r, logical-operators, data-cleaning

I have a dataset with historical data and I want to break it into two sets:

1. The set of IDs that I have their data for at least two consecutive years.
2. It's complement, i.e, the set of IDs that I have one or more year of data from them but in nonconsecutive years.

For example, let's take data set A:

```
A =
ID    Year    X   Y
1     2010    2   3
1     2012    4   0
2     2011    4   3
2     2012    2   2
3     2010    3   1
3     2012    2   1
3     2013    0   3
```

I want to get the set B:

```
B = 
ID    Year    X   Y
2     2011    4   3
2     2012    2   2
3     2012    2   1
3     2013    0   3

B'=
ID    Year    X   Y
1     2010    2   3
1     2012    4   0
3     2010    3   1
```

Note that ID 3 is shown in both `B` and `B'` because it has records of consecutive years and a single year.

I do not have to do this in R, I can use Python as well. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `dplyr`,

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(ID) %>% filter(Year %in% c(Year - 1, Year + 1))
# Source: local data frame [4 x 4]
# Groups: ID [2]
# 
#      ID  Year     X     Y
#   (int) (int) (int) (int)
# 1     2  2011     4     3
# 2     2  2012     2     2
# 3     3  2012     2     1
# 4     3  2013     0     3
```

and

```
df %>% group_by(ID) %>% filter(!Year %in% c(Year - 1, Year + 1))
# Source: local data frame [3 x 4]
# Groups: ID [2]
# 
#      ID  Year     X     Y
#   (int) (int) (int) (int)
# 1     1  2010     2     3
# 2     1  2012     4     0
# 3     3  2010     3     1
```

The idea is pretty simple: `group_by(ID)` to evaluate each `ID` separately, then `filter` to just the rows that have a `Year` value that is one smaller or one larger than all the `Year` values for the group. Add a `!` to reverse the logic and get the rows that don't meet that condition.

Comment: You can translate the logic to base with something like `df[order(df$ID),][unlist(tapply(df$Year, df$ID, function(x){x %in% c(x + 1, x - 1)})),]`, but that's not nearly as pretty.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with base R `diff`

Finding the indices of rows which has 1 year difference in the `Year` column, getting the indices of next row and subsetting them.

```
df[sort(c(which(diff(df$Year) == 1), 
                which(diff(df$Year) == 1) + 1)), ]

#  ID Year X Y
#3  2 2011 4 3
#4  2 2012 2 2
#6  3 2012 2 1
#7  3 2013 0 3
```

and

Getting all the rows which are not part of the first subset

```
df[!1:nrow(df) %in% c(which(diff(df$Year) == 1), 
                          which(diff(df$Year) == 1) + 1), ]

#   ID Year X Y
#1   1 2010 2 3
#2   1 2012 4 0
#5   3 2010 3 1
```

Answer (score 0):

With `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(A)[,  .SD[Year %in% c(Year-1, Year+1)] , ID]
#   ID Year X Y
#1:  2 2011 4 3
#2:  2 2012 2 2
#3:  3 2012 2 1
#4:  3 2013 0 3
```

Or

```
setDT(A)[,  .SD[!Year %in% c(Year-1, Year+1)] , ID]
#   ID Year X Y
#1:  1 2010 2 3
#2:  1 2012 4 0
#3:  3 2010 3 1
```

for the two cases.

Another option is

```
setDT(A)[A[,  {i1 <- .I[(Year - shift(Year, fill= Year[1]))==1]
               c(i1-1,i1) }, ID]$V1]
```